# Sign of the derivatives of a simple function

Tags: calculus, polynomials, derivatives

Consider the function $f(x)=x^b(1-x)^{1-b}$ defined on $[0,1]$, with $0 < b <1$. How can we prove that the even derivatives $f^{(2k)}$ have a constant sign on $(0,1)$? One can show that this boils down to proving that a given polynomial has no root on $(0,+\infty)$ but the coefficients take a complicated form and I have no idea on how to prove that. Thanks!